# generate patch file from git project without commit

Tags: git

I m working on an open source project using git.

I made some modification on the source code ( modify existing file, add new files, remove existing files) and I want to generate a patch file without made commit. How to do it ?

Comment: You realize that commits are local, right? Why not make a commit in a new branch to generate the patch?

Comment: If you have not added it staging area i.e. no `git add` done, then `git diff` will show you difference in form of a patch

Comment: I want to generate a patch file without making a commit on the project. the 'git diff' will not show the new file I added in the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the new file added in the project:

```
git add -N <path of the new file>
```

and then to generate patch:

```
git diff > patch
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not widely known, or perhaps it's just not widely used as a solution on SO, but the output of `git diff` is a valid patch format which can be piped to `git apply`. So, assuming you have an unstaged change you want to use to generate a patch:

```
git diff -- <file> > ~/mypatch ;# redirect diff output to ~/mypatch
```

Then in another repository:

```
git apply < ~/mypatch
```

Suppose you've a brand new file that isn't tracked at all. You can still use `git diff` by specifying the `--no-index` flag and comparing the file with `/dev/null`:

```
git diff --no-index /dev/null <file> ~/mypatch
```

Then apply it the same way.

This answer is mostly an exercise in what git can do. I cannot think of any practical reason not to commit a change locally on either a new branch (via Adam Dymitruk's answer) or to the main branch you're using (per madth3's comment).

Answer (score -1):

make a commit.

```
git checkout -b myfeature
```

first if you like

Comment: I want to generate a patch file without making commit